# UITableViewCell and UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm currently trying to fix the performance of my UITableView. Basically all it is is a custom UITableViewCell with a UIImageView.

At the moment, this image is loaded in the tableView:willDisplayCell: method, however the performance is pretty bad so I decided to try and load the image asynchronously using an NSThread, but this results in the UITableView looking really weird (it jumps all over the place and loads the images oddly).

Does anybody have the best way to load images in UITableViewCells?

Comment: where you are loading images from?

Comment: If you can post the code, it'll really help people to give you a better answer.

Comment: I'm loading the images from my NSBundle (I've downloaded them previously because loading them over the internet was *way* too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried loading it in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and making it a reusable cell?

Comment: Figured out that I wasn't reusing the cells properly. Moving it to 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath also helped. Thanks!